# How can I save image as base 64?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantom js to retrieve the image's strings and then I encode them with base 64.

```
var content = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(imagestring)));
self.writeFile(pathToFolder + fileTitle, content);
```

But images are not displayed. It says they are damaged.
How can I save an image like that?

Comment: Are you working with plain PhantomJS or some bridge between PhantomJS and node?

Comment: Ok, what's `imagestring` and where does it come from? Perhaps you can provide a larger code example.

Answer (score -1):

If you want save image as base64 with JavaScript, you can try with this code:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
// string generated by canvas.toDataURL()
var img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
    + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
    + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
// strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
var data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('image.png', buf);
```

Comment: There is no `Buffer` in PhantomJS. There's also no `fs.writeFile`